About touching which part of mahram women is permissible
My question is that is it permissible for male to massage her mom's or aunt's feet and legs, since these women are old so these parts often get cramped due to work and they ask to massage them. Is it permissible? As there is no shahwat involved?

When someone massage his mother they usually improve the relationship bond to family decrease kibr also can be at the start of obedience even increase  humble so it is recommended to massage our parents when they get fatigue and this is good deeds Allah will reward insha'Allah.
Allah knows the best
